# Why does the magnetic field of a straight current carrying conductor exert force on other magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I've just started learning about electromagnetism, we're taught about the Fleming's left hand rule.. and how it's just Newton's third law in a way. However, I don't understand why straight current carrying conductor's magnetic field reacts with other magnets magnetic field. I am not sure when it attracts, and when repels certain magnets.

Comment: At an introductory level, there is no deeper explanation for why a current carrying wire experiences a magnetic force. It is an element of the world that you have to take as a given, from which you derive other consequences. There is a nice video by Richard Feynman discussing this point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA

Comment: @Andrew Do you take into consideration that it is an effect of lorentz force when you say there is no deeper explanation? I don't think the questions asks 'why' in the sense to which Feynman replies but rather just the mechanism of it.

Comment: @Lost I think the question probably needs more details to be well-defined. I took the question to be: "Using concepts at a novice level, please explain why a current experiences a force when placed in a magnetic field." To which my response is, "At a novice level, the magnetic force on a current is just an experimental fact of life." You are free to add more detail if you interpret the question in a different, and perhaps more accurate, way!

Comment: Physics is more about "How?" than "Why?". It would be useful if you could add some indication about what is your meaning for "why".